# How to find error occurring in getScript in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using getScript function to fetch and execute a js file.

Whenever there is an error, execution stops and I don't see any error message in firebug. No description of error.

I even tried surrounding try catch around getScript, even that doesn't work. So how to find what error occurred while running that script.

Comment: Can you include your js file directly, and see what errors you get? This should at least give you more information

Comment: I can include it directly. But requirement is to include entire js code inside anonymous function. So getScript will have to be used right? Now I know where the error is, at least for this time. That js file is gonna stretch at least 1000 lines. If any error occurs, how can anyone find out what the error was? So is there any handler for getScript function?

Comment: I don't mean include it directly as a permanent fix, just to give you better debug information

Comment: You should definetely debug first your javascript file. Once it is stable, load it dynamically with .getScript().

Comment: hmmm, actually you are right. That should be last step. Will try to put script normally on page now. But still just for knowledge, is there any provision by which we can come to know errors through getScript ?